# Count sum of up and down vote for each item

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my tables, `assets`,`asset_images` and `vote`. Now i need to select asset_id, filename, upvote, downvote for each item. There will be only one image for each asset. So, how can i get asset_id, filename, upvote and downvote for each asset without using subqueries? 
[image: assets]
[image: asset_images]

[image: vote]

I'm expecting the output like,

```
asset_id   filename    upvote downvote
1          5810.jpg    1      1
2          4357.jpg    1      0
3          435657.jpg  0      0
```

I tried with this query,

```
SELECT a.asset_id, (
SELECT count( * )
FROM vote
WHERE asset_id = a.asset_id
) AS vote
FROM `assets` a
JOIN `asset_files` af
WHERE a.asset_id = af.asset_id
```

And got the output as,

```
asset_id   filename    upvote downvote
1          5810.jpg    1      0
2          4357.jpg    0      0
3          5810.jpg    0      0
```

I'm not very good at MySQL Joins. So, please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT a.asset_id, f.filename,
       coalesce(SUM(v.vote = '1'), 0) as upvote,
       coalesce(SUM(v.vote = '-1'), 0) as downvote
FROM asset a
JOIN asset_files f ON a.asset_id = f.asset_id
LEFT JOIN vote v ON a.asset_id = v.asset_id
GROUP BY a.asset_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e91420/3)

Comment: This is not working. I'm getting the values as, http://awesomescreenshot.com/08f29iz756

Comment: @Udhay . . . use `coalesce()` to convert the `NULL`s to 0s.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hey, Thanks for the update. But it still does not return the expected result. Please see this fiddle. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e91420/2/0

Comment: My answer assumed the `vote` column is an integer, not `ENUM`. I've updated it to reflect this change.

Comment: @Udhay . . . I, for one, consider it bad practice to put numbers as values for `enum`s.  It can definitely lead to confusion, and the rules for comparing two values are different than for strings (even though the values look the same).

Comment: BTW, it's a bad idea to use an ENUM whose members look like numbers. See the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I am assuming the values 1, -1 in the `vote` column of the `Vote` table mean up and down votes respectively.

```
SELECT a.asset_id, 
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM vote v
        WHERE asset_id = a.asset_id AND v.vote = 1
    ) AS upVote,
    (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM vote v
        WHERE asset_id = a.asset_id AND v.vote = -1
    ) AS downVote
FROM `assets` a
    JOIN `asset_files` af
WHERE a.asset_id = af.asset_id
```

Comment: It doesn't work. And also i don't want to use sub queries due to performance issues.